# What data is retained in Expo/React Native when you "swipe up" the app on iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I have a weird problem on a TestFlight build where the flow does not match Expo Go.

So in my use case I have an app that would do some things on initial state.  There's a `useState("INITIAL")` in one of the top level contexts already.

On Expo Go when I reload or swipe-up to close and load the app again it works as expected.  But that's likely because it would ask me which app to load again.

On TestFlight that's not really an option because it's one app.

So to get back to my question, is there any data that is retained and restored when you do a swipe up to close on the app and restore it?

FYI: It also works as expected on Android, this is iOS specific

Answer (score 0):

From doing the experiments, it seems that the `AppState` subscription does not get removed when swiping up.  So if you had something that dealt with AppState coming back from `background` to `active` it will fire that event handler.